# vmarg -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError has no effect

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an exported Eclipse RichClient Application (Product.exe) that throws sometimes OutOfMemory Errors (unable to create native thread) and it tried to set the -vmarg -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in Product.ini file.
The OOM Error appaears again but no dump will be written.

Here is my ini file content:

```
Program Arguments:
-console

VM Arguments:
-Xmx448M
-Xms64M
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dorg.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
-Dlog4j.debug=true
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.xml
```

Whats wrong? I would expect to find the dump in directory 
where i started the exe file but it seems it was not generated 
at all or where should i find in in FS?
Or whats maybe wrong with the vmarg?

Thanks a lot for a little help!

Comment: That doesn't look like a `Product.ini` file. Could you please show the exact content?

Comment: `-vmargs`  
`-Xmx448M`  
`-Xms64M`  
`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`  
`-Dorg.eclipse.update.reconcile=false`  
`-Dlog4j.debug=true`  
`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.xml`

Comment: Please check if in _Help > About: Installation Details_ tab _Configuration_ the `eclipse.vmargs` contains `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` as separate line. Maybe the dump is stored somewhere else, e.g. in the Java installation directory (did you start `Product.exe` from the command line or by double-click?).

Comment: The configuration seems to be fine -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError is in separate line. I start the exe via dblclk, I also found no dump in jre installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

What flavor of JDK are you using?

`"HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"`is an option from the Hotspot VM

If you are using another VM (like`IBM J9`) it may not be there and as it is an `"XX"` JVM arg, it could be silently ignored

Comment: This was Oracle JDK 7